# Have to push QPushbutton twice

Tags: qt, signals, connect, slot

I want to make a list of toolbuttons in QT. The toolbuttons should appear in a scollarea. This list should appear when a pushbutton is clicked. I have made the code and it works, exept that I have to push the pushbutton twice in order to let the list appear. Here is my code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);

  find_btn.setParent(ui->centralWidget);
  find_btn.setGeometry(480,250,130,132);

  viewport.setLayout(&scrollLayout);   

  scrollArea.setParent(ui->centralWidget);
  scrollArea.setGeometry(0,116,339,404);
  scrollArea.setWidget(&viewport);

  connect(&find_btn,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(import()));
}

void MainWindow::import()
{
  button.setCheckable(true);
  button.setMinimumSize(317,60);

  button2.setCheckable(true);
  button2.setMinimumSize(317,60);

  scrollLayout.addWidget(&button);
  scrollLayout.addWidget(&button2);

  viewport.adjustSize();
}
```

So when I push the "find_btn", the scrollarea with the buttons inside should appear. At the moment the scrollarea with buttons appears, but only after I click the "find_btn" twice.

I guess I have to update the scrollarea or something like that. Maybe the connect is causing problems? Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options you could try:

```
viewport.update();
```

or

```
scrollArea.viewport()->update();
```

or

```
QApplication::processEvents( QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents );
```

or any combination of them.

Probably the GUI is not redrawn until a redraw is forced by pressing the button again.

Comment: Hmm I tried it but nothing seems to work. I did notice that when I remove viewport.adjustSize(), I didn't have to click twice. But then the size of the viewport is wrong. This I fixed by using resize, but I feel this is not the best solution.

Comment: Have you tried calling `processEvents` after the adjustSize() call?

Comment: yes still no effect. I settled with using the resize function.